# Likelihood function for non indipendent values

Tags: likelihood, iid

We all well know that if $x_i$ are independent and identically distributed a likelihood function will be something like that.

${L}(\theta|\{x_i\}^n_{i=1})=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n {f}(x_i|\theta)$

But how can I compute that if $x_i$ are not independent?

Comment: You do not compute it -- it is something that you know, i.e. assume.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample $\{x_i\}^n_{i=1}$ has a joint distribution, given for example by a multivariate *pdf* $p(\cdot \mid \theta)$. Then the likelihood is 
$$
{L}(\theta \mid \{x_i\}^n_{i=1})={p}(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid \theta).
$$
The *i.i.d.* situation is the case when 
$$
{p}(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid \theta)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n {f}(x_i \mid \theta),
$$
where $f$ is the univariate *pdf* of one observation.